# C++ multithread socket cannot receive client data

Tags: c++, multithreading, sockets

I would like to create a multithreaded socket server. I have the server working fine, but when i try to move my code into a worker function the server stops working when reading the client data.

original code:
main.cpp

```
int sock;

main(){
    SocketServer *ss = new SocketServer(8888);
    pthread_t thread;
    if(ss != NULL){
        while(true){            
            sock = ss->Accept();   
            char* out;
            ss->GetRequest(sock, out);  
        }
    }
}
```

SocketServer.cpp

```
void SocketServer::GetRequest(int msgsock, char* out){
    char buf[1024];
    int rval;
    std::cout<<"before read\n";
    if ((rval = read(msgsock, buf, 1024)) < 0){
        perror("reading socket");
    }else{
        strcpy(out,buf);
    }
    std::cout<<"after read\n";   
}
```

After adding threads:
main.cpp

```
int sock;

main(){
    SocketServer *ss = new SocketServer(8888);
    pthread_t thread;
    if(ss != NULL){
        while(true){            
            sock = ss->Accept();      
            pthread_create(&thread, NULL, SocketThread, &(*ss));       
            pthread_detach(thread);     
        }
    }
}

static void* SocketThread(void* lp){    
    SocketServer *ss = (SocketServer*) lp;
    char* out;
    ss->GetRequest(sock, out);
}
```

Original outputs:
before read
after read

New outputs:
before read

Comment: This is completely broken. What do you think happens, if two connections are received at the same time? There's only one `sock` global variable. And where do you think `out` is pointing to, that `GetRequest` will write to? You need to learn how to use a debugger.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I have only included snippets of the code relevant to the error. out and GetRequest are writing back to main. I can upload other code if needed.

Comment: If you don't know where your bug is, then you have no idea whether these "snippets" are relevant, or not. C++ is not that simple. Just because a program crashes or fails to work in one particular place doesn't mean that's where the bug is. The only thing that can be determined based on the shown code is that there are mutiple fundamental bugs in the shown code.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I figured out the problem. it seems like I needed to specify the size of out. Thanks for the reminder.

Answer (score 1):

This is broken:

```
if ((rval = read(msgsock, buf, 1024)) < 0){
    perror("reading socket");
}else{
    strcpy(out,buf);
```

You are ignoring `rval` unless it signals an error. It should be:

```
if ((rval = read(msgsock, buf, 1024)) < 0){
    perror("reading socket");
else if (rval == 0) {
    // peer closed the connection
    close(msgsock); // or closesocket(), depending on your platform
    break;
}else{
    strncpy(out,buf,rval);
```

and this is also broken:

```
sock = ss->Accept();      
pthread_create(&thread, NULL, SocketThread, &(*ss));
```

The thread started to handle the client has no interest in the listening socket. What it needs is the *accepted* socket `sock`, and it needs to get it in such a way that it won't be overridden on the next call. Typically `sock` is a local variable in the accept loop and is passed via `pthread_create()`.